# Change size circle tikz node

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I would like to reduce the size of the circle, i.e., I would like its boundary to be closer to the equation inside. I've tried to play with the few free parameters in the attached code, but nothing good happened. Do you have any tips?

```
\documentclass[8pt,dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetheme{metropolis}
\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[scale=2]{ccicons}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}

\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand{\themename}{\textbf{\textsc{metropolis}}\xspace}



\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}{\textbullet}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{What do we want to compute?}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    bigcircle/.style={ % style for the circles
        text width=2.8cm, %1.6cm % diameter
        align=center, % center align
        line width=2mm, % thickness of border
        draw, % draw the border
        circle, % shape
        font=\sffamily%\footnotesize % font of the year
    },
    desc/.style 2 args={ % style for the list nodes
        text width=3.2cm, % means the node will be kind of like a 4cm wide minipage, and if the
        font=\sffamily\small\RaggedRight, % set the font in the list
        label={[#1,yshift=-1.5ex,font=\sffamily]above:#2} % add the title as a label
    },
    desc/.style 2 args={ % style for the list nodes
        text width=3.2cm, % means the node will be kind of like a 4cm wide minipage, and if the
        font=\sffamily\small\RaggedRight, % set the font in the list
        label={[#1,yshift=-1.5ex,font=\sffamily]above:#2} % add the title as a label
    },
    node distance=10mm and 3mm % vertical and horizontal separation of nodes, when positioned with e.g. above=of othernode
    ]
\node [desc={olive}{Poisson problem}] (list1) {
};
\node [bigcircle,olive, below=0.1cm of list1] (circ1) {
    \small  \textcolor{black}{
    \begin{align*}
        -\Delta u = f,\quad&\text{in}\;\Omega,\\
        +\text{b.c.},\quad&\text{on}\;\Gamma.
\end{align*}}
}; 
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The context of your MWE is unknown. Do you use this circle just in this example or its style definition should be more versatile, i.e.: that its size can be adjusted locally at each use?

In the later case, you should change node style to:

```
bigcircle/.style args = {#1/#2/#3}{% circle style
        circle,         % shape
        text width=#1,  % for locally determined diameter
        draw=#2,        % draw the border
        line width=2mm, % thickness of border
        align=center,   % for center align of text
        font=#3  % used font
                    },
```

and than write node's code as:

```
\node [bigcircle=2.4cm/olive/\small, 
       below=0.1cm of list1
       ] (circ1) 
{
\begin{align*}
    -\Delta u = f,\quad &\text{in}\;\Omega,\\
    +\text{b.c.},\quad  &\text{on}\;\Gamma.
\end{align*}
};
```

This changes will give the following result:

[image]